# Layout not responding to click event

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I'm making a **custom control** for a `searchview` that should call `onActionViewExpanded()` when a white `layout` that is behind the `searchview` is pressed. It then should make another `layout` appear that, when clicked, calls `onActionViewCollapsed()`. The problem is that the white layout is not responding when it's being clicked.

Here is the `XML`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/whiteLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/customSearchView"
            style="@style/SearchView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:tag="6C45CC26-CB9E-4497-B6E6-6CF725E0C47F"
            android:visibility="visible"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/backgroundLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#B3000000"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the Java code:

```
public class CustomSearchView extends FrameLayout{

CustomSearchViewBinding mBinding;

public CustomSearchView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), R.layout.custom_search_view, this, true);

    mBinding.whiteLayout.setOnClickListener(SearchViewOnClickListener);

    mBinding.backgroundLayout.setOnClickListener(LayoutListener);
}



View.OnClickListener SearchViewOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mBinding.customSearchView.onActionViewExpanded();
        mBinding.backgroundLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
};


View.OnClickListener LayoutListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mBinding.customSearchView.onActionViewCollapsed();
        mBinding.backgroundLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
};
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In your layout, you haven't used the custom 'CustomSearchView' class.

Comment: Sorry, I submitted the edit to my post.

Answer (score 0):

So, you showed us your custom view: CustomSearchView, but I don't see it implemented in layout.

In XML you are using regular FrameLayout and SearchView.